# Rotate Shape on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to rotate the shape x with an click event using jQuery and CSS. I want to target the `x` with an id and toggle a class of `rotate` on and off. The `rotate` class uses the CSS `transform` property to create the effect.

```js
$('#x').click(function() {
  $('#x').toggleClass('.rotate');
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  background: skyblue;
}

#x {
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 9em;
  color: green;
}

.rotate {
  transform: rotate(7deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="x">x</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like homeworks or worse orders...

Comment: @Paulie_D just FYI, the OP did include code, they just butchered the formatting so it didn't appear properly. I've edited it for them

Comment: Check out this codepen, and mess with it for desired results

https://codepen.io/fractaluniverse/pen/VaropQ

Comment: The code was there, I just snipped it, so I don't understand the downvotes

Comment: @OP your code works, you just need to remove the `.` from `$(this).toggleClass('rotate')`. I'm voting to close as a typo.

Comment: you have a typo error in your jQuery....replace `.rotate` to `rotate`

Answer (score 1):

In some functions from jquery such as `addClass`, `removeClass`, `toggleClass`, you don't need to specify the selector with a dot, because you already are telling thats is a class. example:

```
$(this).removeClass("yourClass");
$(this).addClass("yourClass");
$(this).toggleClass("yourClass");
```

Your question fixed:

```js
$('#x').click(function(){
    $('#x').toggleClass('rotate');  
});
```

```css
 .container{
      height: 500px;
     width: 960px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     display: flex;
     background: skyblue;
     }
    #x{
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 9em;
    color: green;
    }
    .rotate{
    transform: rotate(7deg);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="x">x</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is the solution. A little tip. Add a transition to X on transform to make a smoother rotation.

Answer (score 0):

You made an error with your Javascript:

```
$('#x').click(function() {
  $('#x').toggleClass('.rotate');
});
```

you are calling `toggleClass` so you don't need to add a `.` to your selector. so:

```
toggleClass('.rotate')
```

should be:

```
toggleClass('rotate')
```